# Visas for a couple to move to France and form a micro-entreprise

Tags: visa, france, us-citizens

My wife and I are planning to move to France as soon as possible. I think the best option would be if I got a profession libérale visa and then formed a micro-entreprise. What I'm not sure about is how to handle my wife. If she isn't going to work, then does she need to go on a visitor's visa (which she'll need to renew every year, and which doesn't lead to citizenship)?  Is there a "spouse of profession libérale visa" like there is for a passport talent visa? I've read of conjoint collaborateur, and that looks like an interesting solution. She could help with the company without getting a salary, and it would put us both on the French social system. Is this the best way to go, and if we go this route, would we each apply for the profession libérale visa?

Comment: What is your nationality?  What is your wife's nationality?

Comment: We're both Americans.